# How to check Gradle project errors in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, if I have an ordinary Java project, when encounter an error, IntelliJ outputs clear error and location in the 'Run' window like the following:

[image]

However, I have another Gradle project, when run and encounter an error, I got something like this:

[image]

I tried the 3 options, but could not find useful information. How can I find out which line and what error is happening?

Comment: Show the full output when running it with `--debug option`.

Comment: Also try using different(lower) JDK for the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Gradle JVM**.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out just click "run" above shows the error details:
[image]